# Blender suddenly wont open/reopen any of my blender projects

Tags: error

Yesterday I made a few projects in Blender 2.8. All day I was able to save, close, and open them. Today, when I try to open I get an error message saying blender previously crashed, do i want to reopen? when i click "reopen" it's just cycles back to the same error message.[image]

[image]

Comment: did you try to reinstall blender or download a newer version?

Comment: I've reinstalled. I'm using 2.9. I've installed on my husband's PC and tried there. Still froze when I try to use boolean tool. I ditched that file all together, started a new one. Now that file freezes when I use boolean. (I am applying the boolean effect every time, so no stacking here). No one can tell me why this is happening. The only thing I can think of is that my preferences are set up weird or something.